# How old is "Bollocks!"?

Tags: etymology, offensive-language

As a non-English native it took me years to grow up and understand, what meant "Never Mind the Bollocks" as the title of Sex Pistols album. Using "bollocks" as "rubbish", "crap" or what so ever took much more. And after that I somehow automatically bound "bollocks!" with Sex Pistols. Suddenly I understood, that it is so just in my world. Or isn't? Is there some etymology of the idiom(?) ? How old it is in English?

Comment: Well, I'm a native speaker, and I *still* don't really  know what "**Never Mind the Bollocks**" means, so perhaps OP can enlighten me. My best guess is it's a shorter way of saying something like "**Don't bother with conventional society and all that old bollocks**", but it *is* only a guess.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is hard to imagine for native speaker, that someone could listen to the English pop-music without understanding a word of it. As a teenager i had no English knowledge, but Sex Pistols was still cool enough. So, it took a time to get from dictionary word by word meaning (and bollocks=testicles connection, no other meanings), and it was enough as dirty arrogance or something. That was what i meant with understanding it, __verbatim__ meaning. Now i understand it similarly as _your guess_ and i thougth it is pretty common way to interpret the title.

Comment: Well I was a bit past being a teenager when it came out, and to be honest I didn't really get into the punk movement either as music or as an attitude to life. But it seemed very much defined as being *"anti-music"* (Sid Vicious wasn't much of a musician), so for all I know the *bollocks* we were being asked to ignore just meant other people's music.

Comment: 50+ years, in my case.

Comment: An interesting though is the vulgar British English expression ' A good bollocking' meaning a severe telling off... In Tudor times there was a form of dagger, with two lobes on the handle, which with the handle itself. resembled male genatila, this was known as a Bollock knife. This knife was much used by footpads to rob people in the street. Thus if you had had such a hard time, you had had, a good bollocking,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spelling "bollocks" is actually rather recent, the most common spelling before the mythic Sex Pistols' single was actually "ballocks".  Further back in time the Old English form was "bealluc" (testicles) - from Old English "Beallu" (ball).

[Ælfric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86lfric_of_Eynsham) (a prolific writer whose works are an important source for Old English) uses the term "beallucas" c. 1000 (this was absolutely not vulgar at the time and he also happily uses "ars").

Personally I'm tempted to conjecture that there might also have been some Norman influence because the French version is "Balloches" (small balls) and it's still used very commonly in French under this form for testicles (colloquial, not vulgar).
"Alors ? T'as rien dans les balloches ?" (So ? Got nothing in the balls ?).

In addition, the surname "Baloche" (cf. the [America Singer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Baloche)) is specifically [rooted in Normandy](http://www.genealogie.com/nom-baloche/baloche.html).  This time there is no allusion to the testicles.  The origin instead is that "Balochers" were people in charge of a particular type of balance in which the weights were made of small balls.

It might well as well be the other way round however, because whereas the use of Baloche for balance is well attested in medieval French, its use (as "Balloches" with double 'L') for testicles seems to be a later English borrowing.

I'd definitely be interested if some OE or OF specialist could shed more light regarding what I surmise could be mutual influence.

Comment: *the most common spelling before the mythic Sex Pistols' single was actually "ballocks".* That claim is bollocks.

Comment: @Jim, I realise the phrasing is "bollocks".  Reading it, you might conclude that the Pistols changed the spelling from "ballocks" to "bollocks".  That's obviously untrue.  However in the 19th century the dominant spelling was indeed "ballocks".  I went through quite a few dictionaries and some of them, especially ancient ones, had only the "ballocks" entry and others had only "see ballocks" for the "bollocks" entry.  I'll rephrase that in a moment when I have a better idea of when the second spelling came to dominate.

Comment: @Jim, I got hold of the complete OED at last and it has both the ballocks and the bollocks entry.  The latter's first quote is shown as 1744 and c. 1000 for the former.  I've corrected the answer accordingly.  Thanks for the (humorous) remark !

Comment: @Jim Balter: Alain did say "a couple of centuries before". But as [this NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=ballocks%2Cbollocks&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows, *ballocks* was actually more common overall right up until the 70s. Bear in mind that *bollocks* had long been the more common **British** spelling, so obviously that's what the Sex Pistols would have gone with. They didn't *start* the spelling, but they may have been pivotal in popularising a British version over the American one for a change!

Comment: @Alain: Apologies if you want to stand pat, but I just reverted your last edit. So far as I'm concerned you were pretty much correct. Looking at [just America](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=ballocks%2Cbollocks&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3), *ballocks* was more common right up until the mid-80s. The big difference is UK/US usage, and I bet the Sex Pistols were relevant to the fact that the US now follows UK usage. I'm pretty sure it's more British coarse slang anyway, regardless of spelling.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm always happy with people improving my posts. Thank you for your research and please feel free to do it again: it also helps me to improve my readability ;-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why would you look at just America, where the usage of both variants was in the noise until "bollocks" took off, when the question is about English and about the Sex Pistols? I assert that first sentence is still false, and that it misleads in exactly the way that Alain acknowledges in his first response.

Comment: @Jim Balter: I wrote *looking at just America* because my following statement was only true of US usage. Not of UK usage, where the *bollocks* spelling had become dominant long before that album. Anyone who followed [that link](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ballocks%2Cbollocks&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) could check UK usage with one click. Alain says in his first comment (though not in the answer) that it's obviously untrue the Pistols "changed" the spelling. Being young Brits, they just used what to them (and to me) was/is the "normal" spelling.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The answer asserts that 'The spelling "bollocks" is actually rather recent', which isn't true, and implies that it came into use with the SP single, which certainly isn't true. If "bollocks" became more common than "ballocks" after the SP release, which appears to be true, then the answer should just say that and should drop the bit about the spelling variant being recent. P.S. It's not like I care about this, I'm just responding because you reopened a months old thread.

Comment: P.S. Alain's edit comment was 'Changed the phrasing so that readers are not misled into believing the Sex Pistols are at the origin of the spelling variant "Bollocks" as opposed to the mainstream spelling "Ballocks"' -- the rollback resulted in returning to text that misleads in just that way.

Comment: P.P.S. Your first comment here, to me, said 'Alain did say "a couple of centuries before"' -- but I never SAW that, because that was his edit that he made **after** my first comment here. And it's the very wording that you removed. Sigh.

Comment: @Jim Balter: I read Alain's *recent* assertion to be about the *dominance* of the spelling, not it's long-standing presence as a non-favoured alternative. I was content that Alain dismissed the "Sex Pistols coined the spelling" idea in a comment. But he said he would edit to reflect further thoughts on why/when dominance changed hands. His comment didn't reflect the reality that I put in my comment - but I think the whole truth is here and uncontested, if you include the comments.

Comment: ...I know the answer text alone isn't that good, but it's better than any other answer. Probably Alain won't mind at all if you post an answer copying all of his except the bits you think are weak/wrong/misleading. You're more than welcome to do that with any of my answers if I don't edit to reflect valid criticism.

Comment: @Jim. Please feel free to post your answer (I surely wont mind if it is close to what I posted myself). Alternately propose your wording and I'll include it in here if FF is also OK with it.

Comment: As I said, "It's not like I care about this".

Answer (score 4):

Etymonline provides a [different etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=bollocks&searchmode=none):

> **bollocks** "testicles," 1744, see *bollix*. In British slang, as an ejaculation meaning "nonsense," recorded from 1919.

Comment: +1 for having bollocks and ejaculation in the same sentence.

Comment: Etymonline *isn't*, as I write. But whatever they say, *bollocks* does come from OE *beallucas*. Do we really need a first recorded instance to tell us when words like *shit, crap, balls, bollocks* were first used as interjections meaning *Rubbish, nonsense!*, rather than their scatalogical/genital "original" sense. It's not like the written use is going to have started anything, and it may have been around for generations in (possibly dialectal) "spoken contexts only".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Etymonline *is*, and it says just what it is quoted as saying, except that "bollix" is a link to that entry, which mentions O.E. beallucas. As for what we "really need" -- we don't "really need" a lot of things, but we're fortunate to have them anyway.

Comment: @Jim Balter: I have no idea what you're getting at. In the UK *bollix* invariably occurs as *bollix up*, meaning to make a mess of. It may go back to 1919, but certainly this usage [shot to prominence in WW2](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bollix+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). The standard ejaculation has always been *bollocks*, and to me as a Brit, *"Oh - bollix!"* looks ridiculous. Anyway, Etymonline *is*, as you say. And on going there, I think it's ridiculous that they define *bollocks* with *see [parvenu] bollix*.

Comment: ...and my point about not needing a "first usage" was because Robusto is nothing if not diligent in tracking such things down. I just meant that in this case, the earliest one he could find probably wouldn't tell us much, so it wouldn't be worth him spending time digging around. You'll be fortunate if he does this for you; if not, it'll be knowledge you "unfortunately" *don't* have! :)

Comment: "I have no idea what you're getting at" -- I have no idea what part of what I wrote you don't get ... and I don't care.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollocks) has a lot of background on the word, noting it dates in the written record back to 1382, and certainly has had the meaning "nonsense" at least since the nineteenth century.

Comment: Thank you, i read from Wikipedia too. Just looked other views. And got too.